# Don't tell me to review a declined flag on a deleted post

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history, flag-dialog

When flagging a post today it told me to review my flags, because my last flag was declined. As a good citizen I did so, and came to the conclusion that my flag (VLQ) was "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

The post itself is deleted though. Since I don't have 10k I can't see the post, so I can't review the post again to figure out why my flag has been declined. The message is useless for me and will not in any way or form "make me flag better" as there is not enough context to learn from.

Please do not show the message "Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!" in the flag dialog if the corresponding post has been deleted since then. Alternatively allow someone to read a deleted post if they click through to that post from the flag history.

Comment: Well, you still get to see that your flag was declined, so mission accomplished there.

Comment: I think the idea is that you're supposed to review the message that the moderator used to dismiss your flag. Unfortunately, the canned "declined" messages don't provide enough information to be instructional. It sounds to me like that is the real feature request here.

Comment: @Martijn thanks. Deleted some of my comments to clean this section up a bit.

Comment: This is a good idea, not sure exactly how they would implement this though. But you have my +1

Comment: @BurhanKhalid For the alternative solution I would suggest adding `?flagid=123456` behind the link, then checking if that flag 'belongs' to the requesting user and if the flag is declined/disputed.

Comment: @CodyGray I have been thinking about that, but I think a custom message will be of marginal value. I already know the moderator disagrees with my flag. That means they didn't find any of the points in the VLQ flag fitting to delete that post. I can't expect a moderator to explain for every of these points why they think it is not delete-worthy for that specific point, and any other custom reason gives just as much information as a dry 'declined' message.

Comment: Same problem here, one of my "spam" flags got deleted, but I can't check why. How about allowing users to see deleted posts which they flagged and where the flag got declined, so they can see what went wrong? Even if the user does not have 10k rep.

Comment: It's a shame that a very valid feature request like this has received many upvotes, and languishes here, for years. I find this very frustrating in 2020. Having probably flagged somewhere in the region of 4000 questions as NAA and been declined on a handful of them, I don't need 'general education' on the use of the flag, but I find it very frustrating when a flag is declined and the answer is deleted so I can't see why someone might have made that decision.