# When a flag is declined, then the post is deleted/closed later, auto review the flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags

Just seem a comment to [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288062/spam-flag-declined-not-sure-why?cb=1),

> It seems like a lot of questions are effectively "A mod declined my
>   flag and then later deleted the post anyway", and the reason is always
>   "At first glance it didn't look like a problem, but after more flags I
>   looked more carefully", which is perfectly normal and happens all the
>   time (and is, basically, what should happen, given scarce mod
>   resources).

So we need some way to un-decline the flag when the mods look more carefully, **without creating a lot of more work for the mods.**

Comment: Why do we need to "un-decline" the flag?  What's the benefit of this?  Everyone gets declined flags. I don't see the benefit of this.

Comment: @bluefeet, the benefit is feedback to the person leaving the flag and less people asking about them on meta.   Remember most users only flag a few times a year.

If there flag is declined, there are much less lickly to flag again, but flags will always be declined in error whatever is done, so undo some of  the harm when possible.

Comment: @bluefeet those who flag get a "several of your flags have been declined, please review them" and may also contribute to flag bans ([such things do (or have) apparently exist](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1790)). Alternative to this proposal, I would change the state of the of the flag from "declined" to "disputed" which doesn't feed the flag ban in the same way and doesn't warn.

Comment: This would need some careful thought; wouldn't want to validate (say) spam or NAA flags on perfectly good answers that were deleted because someone identified them as plagiarism, for instance. There are rather a lot of edge-cases here (the first being the scenario as a whole; the vast majority of flags are helpful)

Comment: @Shog9,  The easy case is when the declined flag is of the same type as the accepted flag.   Yes these are edge-cases, but on a site as active as Stackoverflow edge-cases effect a greater number of people then the users of most other websites.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269598/dont-tell-me-to-review-a-declined-flag-on-a-deleted-post

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like the larger issue would be the relatively rare cases when a moderator makes a mistake on handling a flag. Rather than some kind of auto-approval (which has problems, as others have pointed out), it seems like this could be addressed by giving moderators the ability to change decisions on flags after they've been processed.

We already have a limited form of this for spam / offensive flags, where we can manually change the state of an accepted flag from "helpful" to "disputed" in order to nullify penalties on poorly applied flags. This is to deal with the damaging effects of targeted flags or mistakes in applying these flags.

It might be possible to extend this to allow moderators to flip other declined flags to being marked as helpful, if a mistake was found in how something was processed. That would target the core of what you're worried about here (like in the linked question).

However, I worry about this causing more drama than it solves. If someone gets a declined flag, and they disagree with it, will they keep trying until they find another moderator to overturn it? An argument on Meta right now about a declined flag can tail off because there's nothing else that can be done about a processed flag. If someone knew it could be overturned, would they just keep arguing about what's probably a minor thing until they got their way?

Maybe such a flag state switch would only be something that could be done by the moderator who handled the original flag, so that it could only be used in cases where the original moderator admitted an error.

Again, I don't know if this would make things better or worse than they are now. Most arguments about incorrect flag handling seem to end well, with either a mistake being admitted or a decision being explained to the satisfaction of the flagger.

Comment: What if a declined flag on a post that was later deleted was changed to disputed automatically?

Comment: @MichaelT - Again, there are many cases where we want to explicitly indicate that flags were incorrect. Some people launch spam flags indiscriminately, and we want to be able to decline those, even on content that was eventually deleted for other reasons. Only declined flags count towards warnings and eventual timed flagging bans, and sometimes we want to make sure certain people get the message about their terrible flags. Another good example are all the "plz answer thiz it urgent" flags we get on questions, that we want to make sure are declined. Many of those questions get deleted.

Comment: What if the state of the decline flat can only be switch at the same time as a modulator marks a flag from ANTHER user as being helpful?    (Maybe even prompt the mod if the new flag is of the same type as the declined flag.)

Comment: @BradLarson You raise a good point. I've argued in the past against proposals allowing users to reply to a declined flag on their flags page. The discussion being private, I foresee users badgering moderators to get the desired action (e.g. deleting a post) even if the flag can't be reevaluated. However, I don't think that the main reason disputes on Meta about flags tail off is because flags cannot be reevaluated. I'm thinking the main factor is the response *from the community*. Someone who raised NAA on something which *was* an answer will be told a 100 times that the flag was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest problem with this is there are going to be cases where someone flagged a post using a flag reason that was completely invalid, and the post ended up meriting an entirely different flag.  In this case, it's *very important* that the flag be declined.  For example, if someone flags an answer as spam when it's not (even if it has other problems meriting deletion) it's *very* important that the post not be considered spam, and that the user know not to use the spam flag inappropriately.

As for cases where the flag really was appropriate, and the mod simply didn't notice the problem the first time around, there simply isn't any compelling reason to do this.  Declined flags don't really *do* much of anything (unless there are so many of them that it's well beyond what's going to happen by accident), if the user notices that the post is deleted anyway the'll have already learned that there was in fact a problem with the post, so they weren't *completely* off base.

Finally this is simply a situation that just doesn't happen that often.  It doesn't merit a huge amount of effort to handle when the *vast* majority of flags *are* handled correctly.  A very small problem that happens very rarely isn't worth spending considerable effort trying to reverse, especially when such reversals have the potential to cause *dramatically* more harm than the problems it fixes.

Comment: Declined flags make people think "what is the point", or "I am powerless" and then leads to less flagging.   We NEED everyone to be flagging spam.

Comment: @IanRingrose And if people are flagging inappropriately (remember the *vast* majority of the declined flags merit being declined) then that's entirely appropriate.  We *want* them to take a step back and re-evaluate their actions to be sure that they're doing the right thing, because they're probably *not* doing the right thing.  In those rare cases where they are, they'll typically be able to determine that while re-evaluating the situation, and thus all is well.

Comment: I think you are crediting a lot of users with more self believe then they have.   People that post on Meta are not typical.

Comment: @IanRingrose Most users don't flag anything at all, or they flag very little content.  Users that ever click "flag" are already not typical.  And users would need to flag quite a lot in order to have any practical likelihood of having a flag incorrectly declined, due to how rare it is.  Those users that flag a lot of content (and that flag a lot of borderline content that a mod is more likely to not see the problem with) are typically users active on meta, users likely to reflect on any declined flags, etc.