# Flag declined, then accepted *for same reason*

Tags: discussion

There's a flurry of questions about declined flags and what happens when flagged posts are deleted anyway. Here, I have a *specific case*:

1. A [post with profanity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062142/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-str-in-python-3-6) was flagged as rude or abusive.
2. A moderator "found no evidence to support it".
3. The post was flagged to mods with the same argument.
4. The flag was accepted on those grounds.

[image: declined then not]]

I've seen [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288201/when-a-flag-is-declined-then-the-post-is-deleted-closed-later-auto-review-the) that discusses the case that a flag is declined, but the post is deleted anyway. My question is more specific because the two flags give the same argument, and they're from the same person. Can these be consolidated in history, so the declined flag is not listed?

EDIT: While there exists a discussion of *whether profanity should be allowed*, the flags were processed in a particular way. My focus is not on the issue of what is allowed. I'm asking about ameliorating the two flags—one declined, one helpful, with similar arguments.

Comment: link to post?..

Comment: 10k+ users can still see it

Comment: Right—though they're on the same grounds, unless I misunderstood profanity as not "rude".

Comment: @aryamccarthy Was the post calling out a particular user or group?

Comment: @aryamccarthy Rude/abusive means the content is directed at someone.  It is different from just profanity existing in a post.

Comment: I might argue that the [Be nice.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) page is unclear on this. It says to flag "**Inappropriate language** or attention. Avoid **vulgar terms** and anything sexually suggestive." It doesn't specify a target.

Comment: @yellowantphil I understand that an automated system wouldn't catch this. I'm curious whether manual intervention is warranted.

Comment: I would have edited that.

Comment: What is vulgar and inappropriate in that post?

Comment: @TinyGiant I'll remember that in the future. Still, I'm more curious about how the flags were handled.

Comment: Some mods have differing opinions on how borderline content should be handled. They probably didn't look to see the old declined flag.

Comment: @rene The inappropriate language was present in the string literals of the source code.

Comment: In that case you have to tune your language filter ...

Comment: @Daedalus Rude/abusive does not necessarily mean the content is "directed at someone;" for example, ["lhasdfkjhasdfak;df" can be flagged as rude or abusive.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317611/3476191).

Comment: @NobodyNada The banner on the linked answer disagrees with your stance.

Comment: @Daedalus How so?

Comment: @NobodyNada It says that the content is an opinion, and should not be taken in an official capacity.  Not to say that my comment should, but the answer in question isn't exactly proof of a point; it's proof of an opinion.

Comment: @Daedalus Sure, it's an opinion, but that opinion happens to be the  consensus (+52/-6).  (Undo only added the disclaimer because of his diamond; the post read too much like an official stance.)  Shog himself also agrees with this opinion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/258777

Comment: @NobodyNada I may have been focusing too much on the 'rude' side of things; I can see how gibberish could be abusive.

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted?

Comment: @aryamccarthy On Meta, downvotes are often used to indicate disagreement.

Comment: There's no profanity in that post whatsoever.  Perhaps you are confused about the difference between (1) profanity, (2) obscenity, (3) crudeness.

Comment: Isn't that splitting hairs too finely? OED defines profanity as "blasphemous or obscene language", and one OED definition of obscene is "offending against moral principles; repugnant".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aside from a few choice words in the code that could easily be edited out, there isn't anything particularly rude or abusive about that post.

That flag is meant for stuff that absolutely cannot be fixed. The entire post exists solely for the purpose of being rude or abusive. Someone copying and pasting their code and forgetting to make it decent isn't a proper use of that flag - that's what editing is for.

Keep in mind that the rude and spam flags have hefty penalties that applies to the user's account if they get validated. Thus, moderators are urged to use extreme caution when validating them. They are not to be used lightly for borderline offenses.